# Sencha Touch 2: Pass data from a panel to another panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, panel

I was wondering myself, how it is possible to pass data from a panel to another panel? The panel, to which I want to pass the data, is defined in the items-collection of the panel, which holds the data. So far, I tried to use the getParent()-Funktion, which looks like this:

```
Ext.define('Sencha.view.MyPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'mypanel',
    requires: ['Ext.Label', 'Ext.Button'],

    config: {
        title: 'Details',
        styleHtmlContent: true,
        scrollable: 'vertical',
        layout: 'vbox',

        items:
        [
         {
             xtype: 'label',
             flex: 3
         },
         {
             xtype: 'panel',
             flex: 3,
             data: getParent().getData(),
         },
```

As you may suppose, it doesn't work. Does anyone has any idea, how I could forward the data and fill the data-config of the children-panel?

Answer (score 0):

You can use controller to call methods in the view, and pass values to them.